# C++ CLI multithread: std::cin text gets overriden by other threads output

Tags: multithreading, c++11, c++-cli, cin

I implemented a multithreaded C++11 console and I have the following loop fetching commands:

```
while (_valid) {

    /* print newline with '>' */
    cout << "\r> ";

    if (cin.fail() || cin.eof()) {
        cin.clear(); /* reset cin state */
    }
    /* random parser function, not relevant */
    _parse_cmd(_input);

}
```

This has a huge problem: when I am inputting a new command by keyboard, if there is a thread running on the background and that thread prints anything, it will override my current keyboard input and it will disappear, but my input will remain on the `cin` buffer.

How can I re-print the current keyboard output?

Comment: Why you let multiple threads access std streams? I'm pretty sure you're doing it all wrong.

Comment: @Windoze I have a logger class encapsulating that access

Comment: I believe the same thing happens in shell and nobody cares. Also if you expect a human being will be using a keyboard to enter commands it makes sence to use something like libreadline instead of plain iostreams (advanced line editor, history and completions to name the few features).

Comment: @NickZavaritsky true, but this is Windows :(

Comment: Are you actually using C++/CLI? Then you should change your tags accordingly.

Comment: You could a) Not log from other threads or b) Log to some other stream and then let the main thread print that later if that's necessary or c) Use a lock while getting input, and during that time prevent any output

Comment: thank you. as I do not intend to have log information delay, I think those options would not fit this purpose :(

Comment: You could also use the Win32 console window API to display output in one area of the screen while the user is typing into another. You'd loose the simplicity of cin and cout, though.

Comment: @TomBlodget that is a feasible idea, although I am not sure I can invest the required time for that.. I thought that cin could have more flexibility